# Can using this function queue::size() of C++ STL in loop affect behaviour

Tags: c++, stl

I am writing code for left view of Binary Tree. And here in the loop when I am putting condition as `i<q.size()` I am getting different(wrong) output and when storing it in a variable and using that variable in loop, **Like**:

```
int size = q.size();
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
```

I am getting correct output when using above code.
Why is this happen?

**Code:**

```
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    int data;
    Node(int val){
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        data = val;
    }

};

void leftView(Node *root){
    queue<Node*> q;
    q.push(root);

    while(!q.empty()){
        int size = q.size();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            Node *curr = q.front();
            q.pop();

            if(curr->left) q.push(curr->left);
            if(curr->right) q.push(curr->right);

            if(i==0) cout<<curr->data;
        }
        
    }
}
int main(){

    struct Node *root = new Node(1);
    root->left = new Node(2);
    root->right = new Node(3);
    root->left->left = new Node(4);
    root->left->right = new Node(5);
    root->right->left = new Node(6);
    root->right->left->left = new Node(9);
    root->right->right = new Node(7);
    leftView(root);
}
```

Comment: The loop condition is evaluated before every iteration. If you modify the size of the queue inside the loop...

Comment: Your post should include the desired output (the "correct" output) and the actual output (the "wrong" output) when configured  as you're described. And note that using `q.size()` in the loop condition takes the *current* queue size. That is relevant because those two push operations vs one pop operation will be a significant alteration to using a `size` static-read before the loop. The latter will execute exactly `size` times and potentially leave content in the queue; the former will execute continuously until the queue is absolutely empty. Unrelated, this leaks memory like a sieve.

Comment: *"I am getting different(wrong) output and when storing it in a variable and using that variable in loop,"* -- to me, this invites an experiment where you compare what works to what does not. You could look at `size` and `q.size()` inside your loop. Perhaps add a diagnostic line inside your loop, something like `std::cout << "Loop " << i << " with size = " << size << " and q.size() = " << q.size() << '\n';`. Maybe also put a similar line after your loop, so you can see the condition that caused the loop to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There code does have different behavior:

```cpp
int size = q.size();
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
```

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<q.size(); i++)
```

The first version has a certain loop size: the current queue's size. The second one has a dynamic loop size, it's not deterministic since in the loop we may push into or pop element from the queue, then each time we evaluate `q.size`, we get a different size. So the second version is mostly wrong and useless.

Your code implemented the level travel of the binary tree, for each level, the nodes that need to be visited is the current queue's size, so the first version gives us the correct answer.

Comment: Got you! Thank you!